# Google bigquery - update sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems you can do select sql in bigquery but can you update only certain rows in the table through api or from their web console?

Answer (score 1):

Currently BigQuery only accepts SELECT statements. Updates to data need to be done via API, web UI, or CLI.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery is a [WORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) technology (append-only by design). It looks for me, that you are not aware of this thing, as there is no option like `UPDATE` or `DELETE` row.

Comment: I was looking at examples on append and it seems everyone get the csv from cloud storage then append to table. Is it possible to skip that and post directly to bigquery to append to existing table?

Comment: Yes use streaming inserts via the API.

Answer (score 0):

To delete data, you could re-materialize the table without the desired rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM [mytable]
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [rows_to_delete]
```

To update data, you could follow a similar process:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM [mytable]
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [rows_to_update]
), (
  SELECT * 
  FROM [rows_to_update]
)
```

Re-materializing a table in BigQuery is fast enough - compared to native update/deletes on other analytical databases AFAIK.